# Regex with pipe delimiter?

Tags: regex, perl

This is my string :

```
my $var = "eval(sometext,'|function|65200|url|click|Chargement|margin'.split('|'),0,{}))"
```

I want to get the number 65200, i tried this `my ($key) = $var =~ /eval.*?\|(\d+)\|.*$/` regex but i get nothing.

Comment: Use Perl's Split function instead of a regex.  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: [Works Fine](http://ideone.com/74tG9l)

Comment: `$var` is just a part of a whole html document, split won't be good imo, thanks for your reply.

Comment: ruby regex is perl regex, so you could use this tool: http://rubular.com/

Comment: for me yours example worked. just added ; in the end of lines and print to show it.

Comment: Yeah it did work finally, there was a confusion with the end of the regex, this one works like a charm `/eval.*?\|(\d+)\|/` :)

Comment: I suspect your problem originally was a newline somewhere causing the `.*?$` part not to match.  you would have needed the /s flag to cause `.` to match newlines too.

Comment: yeah you are right, the variable is just a part of an html document, and the regex and run it or apply it on the whole document, so that must be it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need is the first substring consisting of decimal digits then it's very simple:

```
my $var = "eval(sometext,'|function|65200|url|click|Chargement|margin'.split('|'),0,{}))";

my ($num) = $var =~ /(\d+)/;

print $num;
```

**output**

```
65200
```

**Update**

To extract the first sequence of digits *surrounded by pipe characters*, just use

```
my ($num) = $var =~ /\|(\d+)\|/;
```

Comment: the part sometext might have other numbers, so i need to specify it is between `|`, so this one works great `/eval.*?\|(\d+)\|/`, thanks ^^

Comment: @user2832222: There is no need for all that. See my update.